# Looking for junior full stack developer job

Tags: remote, web-development

I want to work as a remote full stack junior developer . But is there anyone who can give me some advice in which way I should prepare my self . Or what is the best way to get it .

Comment: Do you have a portfolio? Do you have lots of experience in that?

Look at other questions about starting out, as they'll give you more information about what to include.

Comment: I believe I have a stackoverflow career CV . Github portfolio . And a active personal Tech Blog. Can you please give a brief Idea . My CV : https://careers.stackoverflow.com/mahabub

Comment: What you should have and show: Certifications. Thats what business customers want to see to trust.

Comment: By certifications , what kind of stuff get highest priority? Like educational certificates or professional certification?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not agree with the comments. I've been working remotely for the past 3 years doing multiple lines of work ranging from full-stack developer to project management to devops. Certifications are often overlooked, same goes for schooling. There is one, and only one thing that will get you anywhere, experience. Experience can be validated in 2 forms, a portfolio or a customer testimonials/reviews. Many online market places Upwork(formerly oDesk), freelancer, elance, etc. have a review system for customers to provide feedback. This has been a great source of work for me alone.

You may need some initial small projects to find a client. For this I recommend making a blog or personal website, contributing to open source, and creating an online presence. Things people actually look at are you profile on the freelance market, linkedin, and if you're being hired by a company that often hires developers they sometimes look at your github. If you have github contributions its best to provide a detailed description of those contributions, because many people don't know what github is or how to use it. Once you have a portfolio then try bidding on some small, short-term, fixed-budget projects. From there your portfolio will expand as your work, and you're customers will build trust for future clients.

Don't expect to land a comfortable job working from home right away, and don't expect it to be easy working from home. The first year was hell for me. It's hard to get in the routine of working your own hours. Working from home isn't as great as many people describe it, nor is working for yourself. You will end up paying more in taxes, and your taxes will not be taken out of your paychecks like when you're employed. You will either need to pay state and federal taxes out of what you earn either quarterly or yearly. And you will end up paying more in taxes than you normally would because the taxes become entirely your responsibility rather than the company you work for paying a portion of your taxes. Given this only applies to the US(talk to an accountant for more specific information). Its only for some people.

As far as certifications they are only worth it if your doing so to learn something. As far as increasing your ability to find work, they are useless. Same applies for schooling. The key is to keep learning every single day in which ever way works best for you, and the only way a potential client will trust your abilities is experience. A certificate doesn't mean your proficient, it just means you learned something, and in my opinion its part of the job title to be constantly learning.

Following this ideology has led me to be a top rated freelancer on Upwork.

Comment: "You will end up paying more in taxes... state and federal taxes" - doesn't this depend on where the reader is based? I imagine Freelancing SE caters to a worldwide audience.

Comment: You're right, this only applies to the US as far as my knowledge. I know some freelancers in other countries who don't even have to pay self employment tax. I've edited my answer to mention this. Though in most cases, your also paying the portion of your taxes that a company usually would. Given that your local laws require you to pay self-employment tax.

Comment: OK, cool. Out of interest, here in the UK, I believe it depends on the freelancer's choice of taxation route. One can be a sole trader and submit accounts to the tax office oneself, or one can be a limited company and then be legally required to use an accountant. The latter approach allows the freelancer to pay themselves partly from company dividends, which are taxed differently to earnings (it is quite common for contractors to use this route).